# How to read Cookies and Save Session in windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, httprequest

i'm new to windows phone development, I have problem for reading cookies and save session .

For Http request we are using a WebClient and CookieContainer is used to read cookies.

After read cookies using CookieContainer the count of cookie is 2 but while sending back the same cookie to server again for next http request, WebClient is sending only one cookie to server, the server is not able to get the second cookie, so we are getting invalid response from server.

Because of this issue we are unable to proceed to the next process (screen) in windows phone.

Please help for me.

Thanks

Comment: Hi fiskerXO, we are using VS 2012 for windowsphone8

Comment: Did you try using javascript?